# GetSpan() gives NonRecordingSpan in OTLP with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, trace, open-telemetry, otel

I am trying to generate OTLP logs over multiple https calls.

For that I use this function to make a new parent

```
import * as ot from "@opentelemetry/api";

function newParentSpan(tracer: ot.Tracer, headers: any, body: any): ot.SpanContext {
    console.log("start new parentspan")

    //Start new Span with given Tracer
    let parentSpan = tracer.startSpan(headers.spanname as string)
    ot.propagation.inject(ot.trace.setSpanContext(ot.context.active(), parentSpan.spanContext()), headers);

    // Loop over all attributes within body
    addBodyToAttributes(parentSpan, body);

    console.log(ot.trace.getSpan(ot.trace.setSpanContext(ot.context.active(), parentSpan.spanContext())).isRecording());
//This returns false, when I expect it to be recording

    return parentSpan.spanContext();
}
```

However, when I use the GetSpan() method I always receive a NonRecordingSpan
Which looks like this when I try to log it:

```
NonRecordingSpan {
  _spanContext: {
    traceId: 'b199ef0a87a915895a5e16d8bfc6a0c4',
    spanId: 'c605d534f2b18cc5',
    traceFlags: 1,
    traceState: undefined
  }
}
```

I think this is why I'm not able to end the span in a later https call.

I tried to pass my spancontext using headers instead of using ot.propagation like this:

```
    let spancontext: ot.SpanContext = ({
        traceId: headers.traceid,
        spanId: headers.spanid,
        traceFlags: headers.traceflags
    })
```

but most of my methods ended with the same outcome: NonRecoringSpan